# PHP Storm Mark As (revert)

Tags: php, phpstorm

One of my files was "marked as text", with the icon changing. In reality this is a PHP file. I have tried going to `Help -> Find Action -> Mark As` to try to get it back to PHP highlighting but it doesn't work. I've deleted the `.idea` folder, tried to change different settings but nothing works.

What Am I missing? How can I get the PHP highlighting back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to `Settings -> Editor -> File Types`
2. Search for PHP in the list
3. Click the plus icon in the `registered patterns` area and add your file
4. Search for `Text files` and remove the file there